# Mediainfo.dll duration parameter doesn't return seconds

Tags: visual-c++, mediainfo

I am working on a Visual C++ project, and I need to get duration of movie from a chosen file. I use Mediainfo.dll to retrieve this information (`movieFile->General->DurationString;`). The problem is when duration is more then one hour, I don't get seconds, i.e. seconds are always displayed as 00. When duration is less then one hour, everything is fine. I had also tried with `movieFile->General->DurationMillis;`, which returns duration in miliseconds, but I also get 00 seconds. Does anyone knows what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which intermediate layer you use, but from `MediaInfo, MediaInfo::Get(Stream_General, 0, "Duration")` returns a value in milliseconds for sure.
`MediaInfo::Get(Stream_General, 0, "Duration/String3")` will return duration in `"HH:MM:SS.mmm"` format.

Jérôme, developer of MediaInfo

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use  `MediaInfoNET.dll`. The problem is value of `General->DurationMillis`, which should return duration in milliseconds. But when the duration is more then one hour, it always return a value that is divisible by `1000*3600*60`, and that's why I don't have information about seconds. I don't know why is this happening, because in a case of a file with duration less then one hour, everything is OK.

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in MediaInfoNET.dll.
Either report to the developer of this intermediate layer or use directly official VB or C# binding (available [here](http://mediaarea.net/download/binary/libmediainfo0/0.7.72/MediaInfo_DLL_0.7.72_Windows_i386_WithoutInstaller.7z) for example)